# Why is find(1, "1") the first in the call stack?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm reading eloquent JavaScript and I was wondering how the call stack jumps to `find(1, "1")` indicated in the book. I guess I want to clarify what I think. Since the `find()` function is being defined in the local scope of the `findSolution()` function. First `findSolution()` is called. The second function to be called is the return of `find(1,"1")` within the local scope of the `findSolution()` declaration. This also allows the `find()` function to use the parameter `target`. Is this accurate of the interpretation? Sorry if I'm a little confusing.

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
    }

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Comment: Yes. This is called a closure - the ability of inner functions to access the variables available in the outer function

Comment: Note that it does not matter where `find()` is called in order for `target` to be usable. `findSolution()` can easily return `find` instead of calling it and you can call `find()` outside and `target` would still be usable inside `find`